# safely passing a callback from managed code to native code

Tags: c++11, c++-cli

I have a lot of native classes that accept some form of callbacks, usually a `boost::signals2::slot`-object.

But for simplicity, lets assume the class:

```
class Test
{
    // set a callback that will be invoked at an unspecified time
    // will be removed when Test class dies
    void SetCallback(std::function<void(bool)> callback);
}
```

Now I have a managed class that wraps this native class, and I would like to pass a callback method to the native class.

```
public ref class TestWrapper
{
public:
    TestWrapper()
        : _native(new Test())
    {

    }

    ~TestWrapper()
    {
        delete _native;
    }
private:
    void CallbackMethod(bool value);
    Test* _native;
};
```

now usually what I would do is the following:

1. Declare a method in the managed wrapper that is the callback I want.
2. Create a managed delegate object to this method.
3. Use GetFunctionPointerForDelegate to obtain a pointer to a function
4. Cast the pointer to the correct signature
5. Pass the pointer to the native class as callback.
6. I also keep the delegate alive since I fear it will be garbage collected and I will have a dangling function pointer (is this assumption correct?)

this looks kind of like this:

```
_managedDelegateMember = gcnew ManagedEventHandler(this, &TestWrapper::Callback);
System::IntPtr stubPointer = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(_managedDelegateMember);
UnmanagedEventHandlerFunctionPointer  functionPointer = static_cast<UnmanagedEventHandlerFunctionPointer >(stubPointer.ToPointer());   
_native->SetCallback(functionPointer);
```

I Would like to reduce the amount of code and not have to perform any casts nor declare any delegate types. I want to use a lambda expression with no delegate.

This is my new approach:

```
static void SetCallbackInternal(TestWrapper^ self)
{
    gcroot<TestWrapper^> instance(self);
    self->_native->SetCallback([instance](bool value)
    {
        // access managed class from within native code
        instance->Value = value;
    }
    );
}
```

- Declare a static method that accepts `this` in order to be able to use C++11 lambda.
- Use gcroot to capture the managed class in the lambda and extend its lifetime for as long as the lambda is alive.
- No casts, no additional delegate type nor members, minimal extra allocation.

**Question:**
Is this approach **safe**? I'm fearing I'm missing something and that this can cause a memory leak / undefined behavior in some unanticipated scenario.

EDIT:

this approach leads to a `MethodAccessException` when the lambda calls a private method of its managed wrapper class. seems like this method must at least be `internal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After replacing the old method with this new method all over my code base, I can report that it is safe, more succinct, and as far as I can tell, no memory leaks occur.

Hence I highly recommend this method for passing managed callbacks to native code.

The only caveats I found were the following:

- Using lambda expressions forces the use of a static method as a helper for the callback registration. This is kinda hacky. It is unclear to me why the C++-CLI compiler does no permit lambda expressions within standard methods.
- The method invoked by the lambda must be marked `internal` so to not throw `MethodAccessException` upon invocation. This is sort of make sense as it is not called within the class scope itself. but still, delegates / lambdas with C# don't have that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should not be using gcroot but a shared pointer. Shared pointer are made to keep an object alive as long as someone is using it.

You should also use a more c++ style in your whole code by replacing raw pointer with smart pointer and template instead of std::function (a lambda can be stored in a compile time type).

For example using the code you posted :

```cpp
class Test
{
    // set a callback that will be invoked at an unspecified time
    // will be removed when Test class dies
    template <class T>
    void SetCallback(T callback); // Replaced std::function<void(bool)> with T
}

public ref class TestWrapper
{
public:
    TestWrapper()
        : _native()
    {}
private:
    void CallbackMethod(bool value);
    std::unique_ptr<Test> _native;  // Replaced Test* with std::unique_ptr<Test>
};
```

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. This is C++-CLI and you can't put members in a ref class which are not raw native types or ref classes themselves.